# give only authenticated user ability to fetch his own data with Laravel API and Sanctum

Tags: laravel, api, authentication, laravel-sanctum

i have this function for get orders for only authenticated user:

```
function show($uid) {
        try {
            $user = User::findOrFail($uid);
            $orders = $user->orders;
            return $orders;
        }catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(['messsage' => "cannot show order for this user"]);
        }
    }
```

it is a end point for API in this route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']], function () {
    Route::get('/order/{id}', [OrdersController::class, 'show']);
});
```

but now if anyone just add any uid, he can display all orders...
my question is how can i protect this function so just auth user can fetch data: and i have used Sanctum in my project

in laravel with blade i just do like this:

```
function show() {
           $uid = auth()->id();
            try {
                $user = User::findOrFail($uid);
                $orders = $user->orders;
                return $orders;
            }catch (\Exception $e) {
                return response()->json(['messsage' => "cannot show order for this user"]);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all...... I have found the solution, i could find the id of Authenticated user simply by this since i use the guard (sanctum):

```
auth('sanctum')->user()->id
```

this will give me the id for auth user depending on the token.
and the solution will be like this:

```
 function show(Request $request) {
        try {
            $uid = auth('sanctum')->user()->id;
            $user = User::findOrFail($uid);
            $orders = $user->orders;
            return $orders;
        }catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(['messsage' => "cannot show order for this user"]);
        }
    }
```